# app not resume and reopen a new activity after obfuscated by ProGuard

Tags: android, obfuscation

I have developed a application which have obfuscated by ProGuard, [learn from this tutorial](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/07/optimizing-obfuscating-and-shrinking.html).

But the problem is when I click the "Home" button to go back the wallpaper screen (the screen have ur clock and shortcur or widget). Then when i click my application to resume back (my app didn't close before), it will restart a new activity and not resume to my previous activity and then crash!
I have test it before obfuscate, the application was prefect.

Your reply is very appreciated. Thank you.

P/S: sorry about my bad english, hope you guys understand what I'm talking about. Thanks

Comment: You don't get any errors in your log (adb logcat)?

Comment: No, it crash all because of my Arraylist.

Comment: How do you know that without a log? What array list?

Comment: I'm sorry I had make a mistake. it happen even the app was not obfuscate. but it just happen on the 1st time which i run the app after installed.thoredge: let me explain my flow. when the user 1st time install my app it will connect to server to download some information. and app will show basic function(just 1 image) for user when download process running. the app crash because the 2nd app was detect it not the frist time launch the app so it will try to display the other image in screen. but those image was haven finish downloaded by 1st app. sorry about my english, hope you understand^^

Answer (score 1):

You're not guaranteed to get the same activity as you left. If you take a look at the life-cycle model of activity (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) you'll see that the activity may very well go to onStop (and later onCreate) if it is not visible.

Comment: This. If your app crashes because you start a new activity, you have SERIOUS problems you need to address.

Comment: But why it only happen on after I had obfuscate the code? Before obfuscate I have not getting this error.

Comment: I'm sorry I had make a mistake. it happen even the app was not obfuscate. but it just happen on the 1st time which i run the app after installed.